# Why is phpDocumentator not liking my @param?

Tags: php, object, parameters, phpdoc

Hi have a simple function that has a param of object `Person`.  When I run the phpDocumentator (`phpdoc -d . -t /path/to/www/docs`) and see the Errors report I get:

> The type hint of the argument is incorrect for the type definition of the @param tag with > argument $person in addPerson()

```
<?php
namespace MyClass;
...
/**
 * Add Person object to Data::$people.
 * 
 * @param Person $person The Person object.
 */
public function addPerson(Person $person)
{
    $this->people->attach($person);
}
...
```

The `Person` object is also on the same namespace.

I'm looking around and it seems proper.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just ran into the same thing.  My code is also namespaced and the class referenced is also in the same namespace.  I wonder if that has something to do with it.  No idea what the fix is though :(

Comment: I found I could appease phpdoc with MyClass\Person as the type in the doc (NOT \MyClass\Person).  This doesn't seem valid to me and conflicts with my PHP CodeSniffer checks that test documentation matches type hint so I'm not satisfied with that as an answer.  Could it just be a bug in phpdoc when it comes to namespaces?